# help in jquery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I am using a jquery selector

```
$('input,select,textarea').not('table input').attr('disabled',true);
```

here I am disabling all input, select, and textarea control. but I dont need to disable any control that is in a table. I have done it using .not('table input') but I also need to mention `select` along with input control in a table.

I have select conrol in table, whcih i dont want to disable. what would be the selector for this.

Comment: did you try .not('table input, table select') ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input,select,textarea').not('table input').not('table select').attr('disabled',true);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input,select,textarea').not('table input,table select').attr('disabled',true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either use something like:

```
$('input,select,textarea').not('table input').not('table select').attr('disabled',true);
```

Or shorter:

```
$('input,select,textarea').not('table input,table select').attr('disabled',true);
```

But you could also add a class to all your inputs that are to be disabled and simply use:

```
$('.toBeDisabled').attr('disabled',true);
```

Or some not to be disabled:

```
$('input,select,textarea').not('.notToBeDisabled').attr('disabled',true);
```

Or if you want to include all form elements (also buttons), then use:

```
$(':input').not('table :input').attr('disabled',true);
```